# Moving a game object in Arcore

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I have been working out on google ARCore, and got stuck on *how to move the game object with the inputs coming from the android device*.

The canvas that i have created is precisely with 4 buttons, which as AxisTouchButton script from cross platform input covering vertical and horizontal. I have tried out lean touch to scale, translate and rotate seems to works perfectly.But when i am trying to apply force or velocity to the game object, it moves perfectly for the first time, then when i again axis the buttons, it starts to float in that particular direction unless any other button is pressed.

The below code is for the movement of the game object attached to the Andy prefab in HelloAR scene from examples :

```
Vector3 offset=Vector3.zero;

offset.x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");

offset.z= CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

rb.velocity=(offset * speed ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your prefab is drifting with the code snippet you've provided,
Try resetting the velocity to zero after you are done with movement of prefab.

```
rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

Or maybe it is due to the fact that you are moving the prefab too far away from its parent anchor, or maybe away from the plane detected by arcore.

But I've another tested way to move a prefab using touch input on the planes detected by arcore and as it allows you to move the prefab only on the planes detected so you can easily reset its anchor after you are done with replacing prefab.

I'd modified the **HelloARController.cs** script in the following way.

```
bool move = false;   //handle move with some button calls
void Update(){

    //add this in your update method to call MoveObject() method
    //handle move with some buttons
    if(move){
        MoveObject();
    }
}

void MoveObject(){
    if(Input.touchCount == 1){
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        TrackableHit hit;
        TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon | TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;

        if (Frame.Raycast (touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit)) {
            if ((hit.Trackable is DetectedPlane) && Vector3.Dot (firstPersonCamera.transform.position - hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation * Vector3.up) < 0) {
                Debug.Log ("Hit at back of the current detected plane");
            } 
            else {// KEY CODE SNIPPET : moves the selectedObject at the location of touch on detected planes
                selectedObject.transform.position = hit.Pose.position;
            }
        } 
        else {
            Debug.Log ("Not moving");
        }
    }
}
```

here **selectedObject** is you andy prefab of whatever you are instantiating.
Make sure that you are instantiating only one prefab at a time and refer it to selectedObject.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the new ARCore Manipulation System. Working like a charm (for newbies).

They forgot to add a collider on the prefab, so don't forget to add it before running the example.

**ARCore Unity SDK v1.13.0**